# How can I append Mathematica variables to an output file preserving both names and values?

Tags: programming, output

I have a *Mathematica* program that calculates a series of large vectors that I need to save for future reference (in addition to some scalar values). I want to save all these to a file, tagged by their *Mathematica* names, as the calculation proceeds.

`PutAppend` will not work because only the data values are stored, losing their associated names. `DumpSave` does not seem to append to the file, while it does store the values with their names. My goal is to be able to load back the expressions later for further analysis, with the names I gave them.

I'm sure this is simple, but I have no experience with *Mathematica* I/O and can't find what I need in the help.

Comment: Please see my answer to the marked duplicate.  You can use e.g. `Definition[symbol] >>> "file.m"` or `FullDefinition[symbol] >>> "file.m"` depending on what you need.